# What is the curl equivalent command for this code for POST written using DefaultHttpClient library(httpclient 4.5 version)

Tags: java, http, post, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here is the code we are using to hit the POST endpoint -

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            //Create POST with REQUEST_TOKEN URL
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Url + REQUEST_TOKEN_URI);
            post.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            
            RequestAuthTokenBody requestBody = new RequestAuthTokenBody();
            requestBody.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            requestBody.setToken(user.getToken());
            requestBody.setUUID(user.getAccountUUID());
            
            //Generate JSON from object
            String jsonRequest = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody);
            
            //Set request body
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonRequest);
            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8"));
            post.setEntity(entity);
```

Currently this gives a 500 response, but if we remove this code segment below

```
entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8"));
            post.setEntity(entity);
```

It works and gives us a 200 response.

The curl command we have currently -

```
curl -vwX POST [URL(https)] -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[some JSON data]'
```

Are we missing some headers here when trying to replicate the 500 error, cos with this curl we get a 200 response. How to add additional headers with respect to -entity.setContentEncoding() as seen in code to the curl command.
I can assure we have the details for the URL and the json data to be set in CURL to be correct and checked multiple times, the issue only seems to be with the missing headers/header combination.

Comment: try `-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about missing headers just `httpPost.getAllHeaders()`

Here is some ugly code I used to debug my httpPosts as cUrl requests

```
    public String httpPostObjectAsCurl(HttpPost httpPost) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder curlRequest = new StringBuilder();
        curlRequest.append("curl --location")
                   .append(" --request ")
                   .append(httpPost.getMethod())
                   .append(" '")
                   .append(httpPost.getURI())
                   .append("' \\");

        Header[] headers = httpPost.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header: headers) {
            curlRequest.append("\n--header '")
                       .append(header.getName())
                       .append(": ")
                       .append(header.getValue())
                       .append("' \\");
        }
        curlRequest.append("\n--data-raw '")
                   .append(EntityUtils.toString(httpPost.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                   .append("'");

        return curlRequest.toString();
    }
```